# Fitting a graph inside another graph

Tags: graph

I'm trying to solve a problem that consists of fitting a graph A inside another graph B. The graph which is going to be fitted in (A) has less nodes and edges than the other graph (B).

I must find a way to relabel graph B with labels present in the graph A in such a way that all the edges in graph A will still exist in the relabeled graph B.

I believe that must exist a concept in graph theory that could help me doing so. Maybe even an algorithm that could be useful. So, I'd be glad if someone could point me to the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's called the [Subgraph isomorphism problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgraph_isomorphism_problem) and it's obviously NP-complete since it contains the Hamiltonian cycle problem.

Comment: If we knew the specific problem you want to solve, we might be able to suggest a more efficient algorithm than [Ullmann 1976](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgraph_isomorphism_problem#CITEREFUllmann1976) or the good old "try all positions".

Comment: Thank you Jan Dvorak. I really need to study graph theory.

Comment: It's the subgraph isomorphism problem ask @JanDvorak mentioned, here is the original paper of Ullmann: http://www.engr.uconn.edu/~vkk06001/GraphIsomorphism/Papers/Ullman_Algorithm.pdf